# How to exclude dirs in QFileSystemModel?

Tags: qt, dir, qfilesystemmodel

I use this code.

```
 QFileSystemModel* fsModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
 fsModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs );
```

I can not understand how to exclude some folders.

Comment: you can use QFileSystemModel::setNameFilter - but that only allows inclusion rather than exclusion. Other than that you might be able to subclass QFileSystemModel to filter out certain directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing from a standard model is of course possible, but is considered bad style. You'll gain a nice reusable component by implementing a generic filter proxy model. Inherit from `QAbstractProxyModel` and implement a filter proxy.

Comment: how to use filter of proxy model?

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter model and use your `QFileSystemModel` as its source.

For your filter, `QSortFilterProxyModel` has most of what you need - you'll only have to provide a reimplementation of `filterAcceptsRow` to make the decision of which files should be passed through.